# whitelist specific websites in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, whitelist

I have a problem in one of my websites. I'm using a custom made php script to protect my images from being hot linked by new Google Image Search. The script is working but it blocks all other websites from hotlinking, including Facebook, Google Plus, pinterest ...

Therefore please help me on how to whitelist at least these three websites in my htaccess file: facebook, google plus and pinterest.

I tried for example this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^http://plus.google.com\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^https://plus.google.com\. [NC]
```

for google plus .. but looks like it does't work ... what i'm missing here ... ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, what you want is something like the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^http(s)?://plus.google.com [NC]
```

I'm not sure why your rule has a `\.` at the end of the URL but this does really not seem appropriate there.

You can also reduced it to one rule through the `http(s)?` part of the new rule.

But please, think really hard about what you want to do there. Instead of preventing hotlinking by Google, you should either consider robots.txt rules or just allowing Google to link to your images. Everything else can (and probably will with some Google update) harm your sites rank in Google, as you use something that could be easily filed under 'cloaking', which in return would get your whole page marked as spam in the Google index. You can read more on the subject there: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66355

Comment: Google is allowed to link to the images .. but basically the script is sending the image with an watermark ... that's all ...

Comment: regarding cloaking .. as i understand ... you are in high risk when you show different content to google bot for example while showing other content to users ...but i show the same content to google and users ..

Comment: @MirceaSerafim you are totally right about that. Added a link to Googles overview page for that.

Comment: yes - thank you .. therefore i will add that line in my htaccess and see if it works. regarding the cloaking problem i think i am in the safe area ...